# Nested loops print star(*) [python]

Tags: python, nested-loops

[image: Output is:]

The code below is equal to the expected output. I just want to ask why is it needed to print() first when printing a single asterisk, but it is not needed when printing more than one asterisk.

```
n = '*'

for i in range(1,7):    
    for j in range(1,6):

        if i == 1 and j < 6:
            print(n, end = '')
    
        elif i == 2 and j == 1:
            print()
            print(n)
            
        elif i == 3 and j < 5:
            print(n, end = '')

        elif i == 4 and j == 1:
           print()
           print(n)

        elif i == 5 and j == 1:
           print(n)            
          
        elif i == 6 and j == 1:
            print(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

When you are printing a single asterisk, you just do `print(n)`, where `n="*"`.
Note, that when using the function `print`, it automatically inserts a newline character (`\n`) at the end, so that whenever you print something again, it comes on a newline.
But, this can be overridden by doing `print(n, end='')`. This does not put a newline character at the end, but puts the end character at the end.
So, now, the next print would not go to the next line, but continue on the same line.
So, when you want to print an asterisk on a new line, you need to do `print()`, which just prints a newline character and then the *next print* would print on a new line.

Comment: This is my first time learning python, I did not know that the previous argument (end =' ') will still be in effect on the next line when I do print. Thank you for sharing your knowledge. I will take note of it moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

The default `end` argument for `print` is a newline (`'\n'`). Both the clauses in your code that print more than one asterisk get rid of the newline with `end=''` (an empty string). This leaves it up to the next clause to add a newline using `print()`.

EDIT: Clarify what `''` is.

Comment: Ok so whenever I include (end = '') on the code, the next argument will still track the end as ' ' instead of /n even if it is the default output? Cool. Thank you!

Comment: It's important to realize that a newline is a character to be printed, just like letters are. The only difference is that, by default, `print` will print the newline after its regular arguments. By changing `end` to the empty string, you suppress the newline output. The following `print` call doesn't actually "track" anything.

Comment: Got it. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

When you use this `print(n, end = '')` command it will print on the same row.  To make it print on the next row you need to use `print()`. If you do not use `print()` it will continue to print on the same row.